# Fine-tuning an OCR

Tags: python, keras, ocr

I'm trying to fine-tune an existing OCR model called keras_ocr. In order to do so, I followed the instructions provided in the model documentation, which can be found at this link: https://kerasocr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/fine_tuning_recognizer.html.

Unfortunately, I encountered an error when I attempted to fit the model using the provided code. Could you please provide me with specific details about the error message I received? and how I can solve it.
this is the error :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1ffeefaf1864> in <cell line: 6>()
      4     tf.keras.callbacks.CSVLogger('recognizer_borndigital.csv')
      5 ]
----> 6 recognizer.training_model.fit(
      7     training_gen,
      8     steps_per_epoch=training_steps,

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1284, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1268, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1249, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1050, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'lambda_1' (type Lambda).
    
    None values not supported.
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'lambda_1' (type Lambda):
      • inputs=['tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 6), dtype=float32)']
      • mask=None
      • training=True
```